# SwiftUI iOS 17 gradient tab bar - Apple Music

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios17

In IOS17 beta, Apple Music has a gradient with the MiniPlayer.

Has Apple made a public API for this or would a custom implementation be required, if so what’s the best approach?

[image]

Comment: There is not an Apple-provided API to do this.